# getScreenCTM() on svg elements yield bad results on FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, firefox

when working with `<svg>` in FireFox, `getScreenCTM()` does not take transforms applied outside of the outermost `<svg>` element into account.

applying a transform to an enclosing `<div>` will cause unwanted behavior.
here is an example: [JSFiddle: getScreenCTM() not working in FireFox](https://jsfiddle.net/2jpv570s/)

If opened in Chrome, everything works fine. in FireFox, neither the rotation nor scale applied on the outer `<div>` elements have any effect of the `SVGMatrix` that's returned from `rect.getScreenCTM().inverse()`, thus detaching the `<rect>` element from the mouse position.

If you comment out the `#scale` and `#rotate` sections of the CSS file, you'd get a different transformation matrix in Chrome(as expected) and the same one in Firefox which is exactly the problem.

I tried working around this by applying the `<div>` transforms manually, as seen here:
[JSFiddle: Manually Applying transforms](https://jsfiddle.net/bznrs0x2/4/)

This neither worked nor produced consistent result across Chrome and FireFox.

I've seen several reports on Bugzilla from years ago describing a similar bug but these are very old. There are also questions here of StackOverflow regarding the matter but they are not exactly the same, plus the last one was posted in 2016.

I'm trying to tackle this for a while now and I'm at a complete loss. Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use another svg as a wrapper element?

Comment: @AndreNuechter The fiddles presented are a minimal example, the actual element this affects is more complicated. Its an element in an open source web application I'm trying to fix a bug in. not sure whether its permitted to post the a URL to it or not.

Comment: Simplest would be to do what I've just done and try to get the patch in the bugzilla bug landed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is in relations to:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1610093

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This bug is the cause of the problem, I've seen it already as mentioned in the question. What I'm looking for is a workaround that can produce the desired results in Firefox. :)